# Math.max() for variables

Tags: javascript, math

I tried:

```
var maxnumber = Math.max([aantalkeerspeer, aantalkeerzwaard, aantalkeerscout, aantalkeerzc, aantalkeerkata]);
```

And:

```
var maxnumber = Math.max(aantalkeerspeer, aantalkeerzwaard, aantalkeerscout, aantalkeerzc, aantalkeerkata);
```

Neither of which work, I just get NaN. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` on the variables?

Comment: Math.Max is **JavaScript** not **Jquery**

Comment: What are do your variables contain?

Comment: `Math.max(1,2,3,4);` works so it's your variables that are causing the issue.  What are they?

Answer (score 2):

`Math.Max` return `NaN` if one or more arguments are not numbers. Please make sure that all are numbers

Comment: Apparently also string values are accepted: Math.max(1,2,"3") => 3. But of course if there are alphabetical characters included, the situation is different.

Answer (score 1):

The Syntax of `Math.max` is

> Math.max([value1[,value2, ...]])
>
> If no arguments are given, the result is - Infinity.
>
> If at least one of arguments cannot be converted to a number, the result is NaN. <sub>[(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Syntax)</sub>

As per the described semantics, your first approch isn't correct since you pass a single array as arguments, which, if convertable to a number, would only return its value due to the lack of any other, possible greater, values.

You could however use `Function.prototype.apply` to pass an array of numbers as arguments to `Math.max`.

e.g.

```
var m = 42;  
Math.max.apply (null,[1,2,m,3,4,5]) //42 =>
Math.max (1,2,m,3,4,5) //42
```

---

Since both of your versions are failing,
it suggests that one of the variables you're passing cannot be converted to a number, thus the result is `NaN`

<sub>Note that the variable, passed, does not necessarily have to be of the type number, as long as it is convertable to one. *e.g* the following example returns 3</sub>

```
Math.max ({valueOf: function () { return 1; }},{valueOf: function () {return 3;}}); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.max()
```

function will check the maximum value for group of numbers only, not a string. that's only you got answer NaN.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very late answer but this is for the people looking up this question. In my humble opinion, the rest of the answers are either incomplete or kinda confusing for a beginner like me. The problem is that the variables are strings, which just won't work in a `Math.max()`. Personally what worked for me was `parseInt()`, which basically converts a string into a whole number. You could also use `parseFloat()` to convert it into a number with decimals. Alternatively, `Number()` can convert it to both, although if text enters the string, it will return NaN.

Here I provide an example:

```html
<p id="display"></p>

<input id="firstone" type="number"></input>
<input id="secondone" type="number"></input>
<input id="thirdone" type="number"></input>

<br>

<button onclick="biggestnum();">Which is the biggest?</button>

<script>
    function biggestnum(){
    var input1 = document.getElementById("firstone").value;   
    var input2 = document.getElementById("secondone").value;  
    var input3 = document.getElementById("thirdone").value;
    var x = parseInt(input1, 10)
    var y = parseInt(input2, 10)
    var z = parseInt(input3, 10)
    var maximum = Math.max(x, y, z);
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = maximum;
}
</script>
```

this basically allows numbers that are entered into inputs to run in the `Math.max()`. Another important thing to note about `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` is that you have to specify the numerical base (which will usually be 10).